NotFoundHttpException with ApiPlatform: Custom URL Parameter Treated as Identifier
I'm encountering an issue within my Symfony project that utilizes ApiPlatform. Whenever I include a custom parameter in the URL, I face a NotFoundHttpException with the message "Invalid URI variables". It seems that ApiPlatform, within Symfony, is interpreting my custom URL parameter as an identifier instead of a variable.
Here's a snippet of the relevant code:
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/{tenant}/agreement',
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                parameters: [
                    new Model\Parameter(
                        name: 'tenant',
                        in: 'path',
                        required: true,
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ]
)]

My goal is to include this custom parameter in the SQL query condition for retrieving the collection.
I suspect that ApiPlatform might be misinterpreting the parameter configuration. I'm seeking guidance on how to address this issue and ensure that ApiPlatform correctly handles the custom URL parameter as a variable rather than an identifier. Any advice or insights on resolving this matter would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Should you not use a filter for what you are trying to achieve ?  And then your url would be like "/agreement?tenant=xxxxxxxx

I don't want just a simple filter, there's rights management behind it and that's part of the specs I've received.

I found a solution:
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/{tenant}/agreement',
            uriVariables: [],
            routeName: 'api_agreement',
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                parameters: [
                    new Model\Parameter(
                        name: 'tenant',
                        in: 'path',
                        required: true,
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ]
)]

Both a uriTemplate and a routeName must be set for the route to be correctly handled. Additionally, setting uriVariables: [] allows for "disabling" the "id" parameter.
Then, you can create a controller, assign it a route (the same as the one indicated in the entity), which allows for manually handling the request (we'll need to generate the response ourselves).
I couldn't find a better solution, but if this one can help someone, it's worth sharing. If you have a better solution, feel free to share it.
